# agGrid rollup example shows missing ClientSideRowModelModule

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, rollup

I tried to execute the minimal rollup example that ag-grid shows at their page. But no matter what, I won't get it to work. The Error I get is:

```
ag-Grid: could not find matching row model for rowModelType clientSide
Row Model "Client Side" not found. Please ensure the ClientSideRowModelModule is loaded using: import '@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model';
```

I tried importing `ClientSideRowModelModule` and `ClientSideRowModel`, as stated in the error, but that changes nothing.

I tried and stepped through the bundled code and it seems that it is not possible for aggrid to access their own modules, although they are present.

I uploaded the example to github, just clone, `npm i && npm run rullup` and then open the index.html file.
https://github.com/dennis-f/ag-grid-clientsiderowmodel-bug

```
git clone git@github.com:dennis-f/ag-grid-clientsiderowmodel-bug.git
npm i && npm run rollup
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed, to get it to work.

Old:

```
import {Grid} from '@ag-grid-community/all-modules';
```

New:

```
import {AllCommunityModules, Grid, ModuleRegistry} from '@ag-grid-community/all-modules';
ModuleRegistry.registerModules(AllCommunityModules);
```

I don't know why this is missing in all those examples, but you need to register your modules manually, even if you use the '`all-modules`' package.

It is not aware, that all modules should be loaded on startup. It's a nice solution, but unfortunately it's only explained [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-modules/#installing-ag-grid-modules).

Instead of `AllCommunityModules` you can obviously load only the ones you actually need.